# Trying to find a firework or Roman candle with a guild steersman on it

Tags: object-identification, art

Of late, I have decided to start asking here all the various science fiction and fantasy questions that have puzzled me over the years.  Today, I have a *fireworks identification question*.

I know this sounds silly, but bear with me here.

About twenty years ago, I came home from college for a few weeks in the summer.  My younger brother informed that, for Independence Day, they had bought a small firework with a picture of a guild steersman from Dune on it.  I was incredulous, so he showed it to me.  It was a large firework, the kind you set on the ground, and it shoots sparks in the air, like several Roman candles tied together and run on a single fuse.  On the side of the packaging, it featured a large angry alien, facing out at the viewer and tearing up some skyscrapers.

"Huh," I said.  "That does look kind of like the guild in *Barlowe's Guide to Extraterrestrials*.

"No," my brother said, "it looks exactly like it."

So we pulled out *Barlowe's Guide*.

[image: Guild Steersman]

I remember the alien's skin color as not being quite the same (less blue, more gray, I think), and the fingers were more like tentacles tearing apart the nearby buildings.  However, the shape of the face really was *exactly* the same.  Whoever had drawn the firework packaging had clearly copied from the book.

I wanted to show this image to somebody else recently, but I could not find it online.  I think the name of the firework was actually "Rocky Mountain High," but that is unfortunately a pretty common brand name for fireworks (*...I've seen it raining fire in the sky...*).  I have not been able to locate this via Google.  So I'm wondering where I could find an image of this, and, moreover, if there's any information out there about how a giant guild steersman came to be attacking Colorado Springs.

Comment: Could it be Cthulhu or similar creature?

Comment: @eshier It would have looked Cthulhu-oid, had we not been familiar with Barlowe's guild illustration.

Comment: The last sentence confuses me. What does Colorado Springs have to do with the question? Is that supposed to be a joke?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd It was a joke about how the name, "Rocky Mountain High" seemed to be an allusion to something utterly different (the song by John Denver, about Colorado).